# Write update statement in Python Elixir

Tags: python, sql, orm, python-elixir

I'm using Elixir as my ORM for a MySQL database, I'm having problems writing an update statement, for instance:

```
"update products set price=NULL where id>100"
```

This is my Elixir clsee

```
class Product(Entity):
    using_options(tablename='model_product')
    name                        = Field(Unicode(200))
    en_name             = Field(Unicode(200))
    price                       = Field(Float)
    en_price            = Field(Float)
    productid                   = Field(Unicode(200))
    site                        = Field(Unicode(30))
    link                        = Field(Unicode(300))
    smallImage                  = Field(Unicode(300))
    bigImage                    = Field(Unicode(300))
    description                 = Field(UnicodeText)
    en_description              = Field(UnicodeText)
    createdOn                   = Field(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    modifiedOn                  = Field(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    size                        = Field(Unicode(30))
    en_size                     = Field(Unicode(30))
    weight                      = Field(Unicode(30))
    en_weight                   = Field(Unicode(30))
    wrap                        = Field(Unicode(30))
    en_wrap                     = Field(Unicode(30))
    material                    = Field(Unicode(30))
    en_material                 = Field(Unicode(30))
    packagingCount              = Field(Unicode(30))
    stock                       = Field(Integer)
    location                    = Field(Unicode(30))
    en_location                 = Field(Unicode(30))
    popularity                  = Field(Integer)
    inStock                     = Field(Boolean)
    categories                  = Field(Unicode(30))
```

How should I be doing this?

Comment: how are your model class(es) defined?

Comment: @ma3204 the class define as above listed

Answer (score 0):

Try to think in terms of objects, not SQL, which is the reason for having an ORM.
I pretty much just followed the [elixir tutorial](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki/TutorialDivingIn) with your class:

```
for p in Product.query.filter(Product.id > 100):
    p.price = None
session.commit()
```

In SQLAlchemy, Python's `None` maps to a `NULL` in SQL: [Common Filter Operators](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the SQLAlchemy way to do this, note that elixir does not intended to replace how SQLAlchemy works in many case.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

sa.update(Product.table).\
    where(Product.id > 100).\
    values(price=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case sombody stumbles upon this question, this should work in Elixir:

```
Product.query.filter(Product.id > 100).update({Product.price: None})
```